# Confusion with sentences use of klingen and ihnen

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, grammar-identification

> Unsere Schritte klingen ihnen zu einsam durch die Gassen.
>   (Our footsteps in the streets sound too lonely to them.)

I take it that the translation of *to them* is *ihnen* in German. How does the construct work? Does *klingen* take the dative? Why is there an omission of *zu*, like *zu ihnen*? Is it not possible to say the following?

> Unsere Schritte klingen zu ihnen zu einsam …

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*klingen* does not necessarily take the dative. The background is more general:

Verbs of sensing (like "klingen, sehen, hören, riechen") take the dative for the *recepient of the sensing*.

> Die Schritte klingen ihnen zu einsam
>
> Das Kleid sieht mir aber teuer aus
>
> Der Ausflug hörte sich ihm zu gefährlich an
>
> Das roch ihnen zu stark nach Betrug

This is BTW the same in English:

> This sounded too lonely to him

The "zu" (or "to") is not needed (or rather: wrong) in German, because there is still an *alive dative* in this language, while English needs a preposition ("to") to signal this case.

This is one of the fundamental differences between the two Germanic languages English and German: English mainly drives relationships by prepositions, German by cases (**and** prepositions).